# How to solve it when make the mod_python?

Tags: python, django, apache-http-server

the verison of RPM is:

httpd-2.2.3-63.el5.centos.1
httpd-devel-2.2.3-63.el5.centos.1
apr-1.2.7-11.el5_3.1
apr-devel-1.2.7-11.el5_3.1
apr-util-1.2.7-11.el5
apr-util-devel-1.2.7-11.el5

the version of Python is 2.7
the version of mod_python is mod_python-3.3.1

My OS is:
Linux YF-23-73 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 14:58:14 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

when I install mod_python, I do like:
**./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs**

and 
**make**

the error messages is:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make[1]: *** [mod_python.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/python_mod/mod_python-3.3.1/src'
make: *** [do_dso] Error 2
```

How to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Python installation must be configured with `--enable-shared` when installed.

Please be aware that the mod_python project is officially no longer developed or supported.

You should really look for alternatives. You certainly shouldn't be using it for new projects.

In addition, keep in mind that Django has support has been deprecated for using mod_python. It may have even removed the support already.